# How to fix UI-route where route loads the previous view as well beneath the current view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular and i have started with angular1 ui-route. When I am moving from one view(view1) to another(view2), view 2 loads up fine but as i scroll down i discovered, view 1 appears beneath view 2. The issue is observed only during navigation through ui-route. On page reload/refresh i find, it works fine. Unable to figure out the reason.

Library version :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

On moving from dashboard to users view, Users view loads with dashboard view beneath it.There is no ui-view else where in the app apart from within the body tag. Other pages are just templates/common html pages.

```
HTML :
<body ng-app="NoticeboardApp" ng-cloak>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>


Route :
<a ui-sref="users"></a>
<a ui-sref="notifications"></a>

app.js :
.state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'pages/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
    })
    .state('users', {
        url: '/users',
        templateUrl: 'pages/user.html',
        controller: 'userCtrl'
    })
    .state('notifications', {
        url: '/notifications',
        templateUrl: 'pages/notification.html',
        controller: 'notificationCtrl'
    })



After routing, inspect element code shows two ui-view :
[inspect elements code][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa1hW.png
```

Comment: Just observed that on refresh it does not loads beneath the other view not because it does not exist, but it exists as an empty view. Observation from inspect element code. Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I am remembering correctly there was a bug in ui-router which you can solve by scrolling to top when your new page loads.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```